# Getting php variable back to a form

Tags: php

I have a form which i'm Posting information to a php script. The issue i have is that i dont want to be sent to the PHP page, i just want it to process the information and send a PHP $variable to my textarea object (input)

```
 <div class="form">
                <form name= "form" action="function_script.php" method="post">
                    Please enter an integer value: <input type="text" name="num" id="numb" ><br><br>
                    <textarea name='input' id="input"></textarea><br>
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
            </div>
```

What do i need to do on the PHP side so it passes the information back on to the form to display.

Comment: For textareas, put `<?php echo isset($_POST['input']) ? $_POST['input'] : ""; ?>` between the textarea tags. For HTML inputs, use it as the `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset($_POST['input'])` to set value

```
<div class="form">
    <form name= "form" action="function_script.php" method="post">
        Please enter an integer value: <input type="text" name="num" id="numb" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['input']) ? $_POST['input'] : ''; ?>" >
        <br><br>
        <textarea name='input' id="input"><?php echo isset($_POST['input']) ? $_POST['input'] : ""; ?></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `$_POST['input']` for the number too? This looks very much like my comment though ;-)

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, sorry. So what do i need to do in the "function_script.php" to bring back say a variable $result and add that to textarea.